# Anyone got an "for dummies" guide to PayPal's digital goods in Flash?

Tags: flash, paypal

I'm a Flash designer and developer (in that order) and while I love the idea of PayPal's digital goods interface I'm a bit stumped by their literature and I was wondering if anyone had a "for dummies" guide or a "step by step" explanation of how to implement it in Flash ?

I've got a PayPal business account and a site ready to use the interface - just need some basic help with moving from "I'd like to do that" to actually implementing it.

All and any help much appreciated.

Best wishes
Monty

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking the wrong question. And I do not believe there is such a book.
In short what you want to learn is a little bit of a prepossessing language such as php and database interaction.
I do know there is a book that covers php/mysql with flash.

What you need to do is use paypals IPN(instant payment notification). Someone buys something, paypal will send that information to a page that will verify the information. If the information is verified you save it into database. the customer is redirected to a page you specified in paypal settings and on that page you will access the database and let them download the product if the have successfully made the purchases.

p.s here is a link to the book I mentioned
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470258241.html
paypal ipn link
https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: I know php pretty well and didn't realise I could do it that way. My main interest is keeping the user on the page (no pop up to go to paypal) and that's what attracts me to the digital goods thing.